# Touch-action movement from last to first in html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using touch-action property in my carousel, it auto slides too and there is no problem in it. What i am trying to do is, when i am scrolling slider using touch-action, it slides but when it comes on last slide it stops. I just want that, it doesn't stop and came to first slide.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="testimonial">
                        <div class="pic">
                            <img src="image/pay.png">
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="title">Williamson</h3>
                        <span class="post">Web Developer</span>
                        <p class="description">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial">
                        <div class="pic">
                            <img src="image/pay.png">
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="title">Kristina</h3>
                        <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
                        <p class="description">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my css :

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
.owl-carousel{display:none;position:relative;width:100%;touch-action:default;}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{display:none;position:relative;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:100%}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{-webkit-transition:height 500ms ease-in-out;-moz-transition:height 500ms ease-in-out;-ms-transition:height 500ms ease-in-out;-o-transition:height 500ms ease-in-out;transition:height 500ms ease-in-out}

.owl-carousel .owl-item{float:left}.owl-controls .owl-page,.owl-controls .owl-buttons div{cursor:pointer}.owl-controls{-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}.grabbing{cursor:url(grabbing.png) 8 8,move}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,

.owl-carousel .owl-item{-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
```

Here is my script :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        itemsDesktop:[1000,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1],
        itemsTablet:[768,1],
        transitionStyle:"backSlide",
        autoPlay:true
    });
});
```

Comment: use `loop:1` in your owlCarosel instance

Comment: but where to add

Comment: Can you create a snippet by editing your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owl Carousel had a built in loop option just use the `loop:true` Refer documentation : https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        itemsDesktop:[1000,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1],
        itemsTablet:[768,1],
        transitionStyle:"backSlide",
        autoplay:true,
        loop:true // for looping ref https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle Preview : https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/eaq0978s/

Comment: @Bhawesh, can you check at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/eaq0978s/. Its works fine

Comment: @Bhawesh, cool loop is working, let me look into auto play now.